# Powershell Add a value with current time to get calculated time

Tags: powershell, time, scripting, window

I want to add days or hours or minutes to the current time get my calculated time . As of now I'm using below code , it is working but is there any way we could improve

```
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Days 0 -Hours 8 -Minutes 40

$ot = (get-date) + $ts 

$ft = get-date $ot -Format hh:mm
```

Above code can give you a calculated time but can we make it into a single line  ?

Comment: `((Get-Date) + '00:08:40:00').ToString('hh:mm')`

Comment: Related: [`#14501` Type cast TimeSpan to DateTime relative to now (Get-Date)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14501)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine all of that into a single line as

```
$ft = (Get-Date) + (New-TimeSpan -Days 0 -Hours 8 -Minutes 40) | Get-Date -Format hh:mm
```